# plotting a sequence results in: "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm a beginner here and I'm experiencing a problem when I'm trying to plot a sequence:

My code gives me this error message:
"ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"

```
hold(True)
x=[0.5]
for r in arange(2,4,0.1):
    for i in range(170):
        xn= x[-1]
        xnp1 = r*xn*(1-xn)
        x.append(xnp1)
        xa=array(x)   
        rplot=0*xa+r
plot (rplot, xn,".")
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to plot `xn` (the dependent variable, aka "the y-data") versus `rplot` (the independent variable, aka "the x-data").

From your code, you'll see that `xn` refers to the last item in the array `x`, so it is a *single* scalar. `rplot` however is as long as the array `x`, because you made it such:

```
rplot = 0*xa + r
```

It's like plotting the number "1" to more than one x-value (like `[1, 2, 3]`). You can see that this is confusing, right?

It's not clear what exactly you want to plot (which variables against which other variables), but this post does answer why you're getting that error. Perhaps it'll help you in finding out what you really want to plot.

Based on the received comment, you might be looking for this code:

```
hold(True)
x = [0.5]
for r in arange(2,4,0.1):
    for _ in range(170):
        xn = x[-1]
        x.append( r*xn*(1 - xn) )
    rplot = np.full(len(x), r)            
    plot(rplot, x, ".")
show()
```

It plots, for every `r` within the `range(2, 4, .1)` an array of points, which depend on that value. The array of points for that particular value of `r` all have the same ordinate, which is `r`. It looks like stripes.

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt seem to have solved the problem, i think the issue mught have to do with the location of "for r in arange(2,4,0.1):" line, but im not sure

Comment: @BrigidMaloney perhaps you can give more details about what you want to plot (which variables against which variables). I've been looking at your code for a while now, but I have absolutely no idea what you could be interested in.

Comment: for every value of x defined as xnp1, which i want to use as my y value, i want to plot an r within the range, as the x value, which is why i added a hold(True) in order to allow the points that fall on the same location to be plotted over instead of being erased, so multiple values could be achieved for each value of r

Comment: @BrigidMaloney perhaps the code I've edited in is what you're looking for? Notice the changes to the indentation.